# Derive strict type from class that is validated

Tags: typescript, validation, types

I have a Typescript class that can be validated, and after validation the type of its fields are guaranteed. But the validatable class needs to be permissible to accept user input. Can I use a derive a strict type from the permissible class?

**Basically**: I have a class whose implicit interface is `{value: string | undefined}` and I want to automatically derive `{value: string}` type from it.  Is that possible?

In more concrete terms I have a class like this:

```
class Validatable {
  value: string | undefined = undefined
}
```

(in my actual code this must be a class because of how validation works, but I don't think the details of validation matters for this question)

That class can be validated ala:

```
function getValid (inst: Validatable) {
  const errors = validate(inst)
  if (errors.length > 0) throw new Error("Invalid")
  return inst
}

const inst = new Validatable()
inst.value = "foo"
getValid(inst).value
                ^-- this type is string | undefined 
                    but we know it must be string
```

What I'd like is to automatically derive the `{value: string}` strict interface. Is that possible?

Comment: Decorators don't show up in the type of the class in any way. The only way to do this is to manually add some sort of marker to the prop type or use functions instead of decorators to mark the props we want to validate (with functions we could add this information, something like `validationBuilder.validate(Length(2, 10), "value")`)

Comment: I don't think decorators need be involved in this. I have a class whose implicit interface is `{value: string | undefined}` and want to derive `{value: string}` type from it. I included the decorator business to highlight why the permissive type must be a class. I'll update the question to highlight this simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to remove all the `| undefined` from a type you can use a mapped type:

```
class Validatable {
  value: string | undefined = undefined
}
type RequiredNotNullOrUndefined<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: Exclude<T[P], null | undefined>
}

function getValid (inst: Validatable) {
  return inst as RequiredNotNullOrUndefined<Validatable>  // <-- we can guarantee field type now
}

const inst = new Validatable()
inst.value = "foo"
getValid(inst).value // string
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEBqYgJYBMwBcwCMQFNoG8AoaaANwQFccAuaCNAJ0QDsBzaAH2gueRwDMWOZNAC83XgKHJCAX0JoAngAc8AJRwBHCogbCAcgHs0+iiBAB5BgFVJg5sIA8AFQB8YgsWgBtAArQWaABrHEVDfmhnAF0AWgB+WgBRAA9QCj4XPyiAGmhmMxBOCT57YVc5QkJ+HmA0RENmaFYcNHgkEQAKFnpaNpR0LFwASk8SPTQKBkbutGhIaA1tXQNjU3MrWxLpRz7UDGwcd2gAemPoRxiY6AB3PGAwRtYKMAYHtBw8QRwQESVVPMM1wqhGADXoAWY4PEDmucAQ-X2uA6Q0IMwAdOQQFQPAAifiGQw4wjNVrw5BdSFoIYYyh4U50RgsVhAA)

**Note:** The `RequiredNotNullOrUndefined` is similar to the predefined type `Required` but `Required` will only remove optionality from a type, will not remove `| undefined | null` from the any property type, this version does.